# Arduino float - 6 decimal numbers

Tags: arduino

I wonder if anyone has a good solution for decimal numbers.

I use a Arduino Mega, and try to convert a float with 6 numbers after decimal point. When I try, I get 5 numbers correct, but not number 6. The 6 number is either not counted, or shown as 0. I have tried a lot of different things, but it always end up showing 5 numbers correct, but not 6.

Do anyone has a solution for this?

Appriciate all help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you can use scaled integer forms of floating-point numbers to preserve accuracy.

Specifically, if these are lat/lon values from a GPS device, you might be interested in my [NeoGPS](https://github.com/SlashDevin/NeoGPS).  Internally, it uses uses 32-bit integers to maintain 10 significant digits.  As you have discovered, most libraries only provide the 6 or 7 digits because they use `float`.

The example NMEAloc.ino shows how to print the 32-bit integers *as if* they were floating-point values.  It just prints the decimal point at the right place.

The NeoGPS distance and bearing calculations are also careful to perform math operations in a way that maintains that accuracy.  The results are very good at small distances/bearings, unlike all other libraries that use the `float` type in naive calculations.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that :)

Answer (score 0):

4 byte floats  can hold 6 significant digits.
8 byte doubles can hold 15.

You need to use doubles to get the precision you want.

[info on 4 byte floats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format])

Comment: [Arduino's doubles](https://www.arduino.cc/en/reference/double) are also just 4 bytes.

Comment: I have tried to do like this:

double lat;

 String streng;

lat = 59.123456;

streng = String(lat,6);

But it only show like:59.123455